# Cannot invoke instructions. Missing package "@adonisjs/core"

Tags: adonis.js

I am trying do:
npm init adonis-ts-app blog

And I am getting this issue: Cannot invoke instructions. Missing package "@adonisjs/core"

Can someone help me about this issue? I am using AdonisV5

Answer (score 0):

I installed the GIT com **sudo apt install git** and solved it!!